# how to get the list of filenames while reading a directory in SparkR

Tags: r, hdfs, sparkr

I'm reading the data present inside a directory at HDFS using `read.df()` method in SparkR.

The code which I used for reading the directory is,

```
df <- read.df(path="wasb://<spark_cluster_name>..blob.core.windows.net/<directory_name>",source="com.databricks.spark.csv",header="true");
```

I wanted to know the list of filenames present inside the directory while reading. Please suggest me a favorable solution with examples.